# Python ConcurrentLogHandler: force rollover when using with Tornado HttpServer

Tags: python, logging, tornado

I'm using the ConcurrentLogHandler to log my Python application log messages to a file. Tornado's HTTPServer is used in production as the server, and in certain condition (user form submit), I would like to force the roll over of the file.
The issue I'm having is, when running logger.handlers[0].doRollover(), the roll over does not happen, and I don't see an error either.

Many modules of my apps import the "logger" object from the following module to write to the log:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
from cloghandler import ConcurrentRotatingFileHandler
from my_app import app

logger = logging.getLogger('my_app')
hdlr = ConcurrentRotatingFileHandler(app.config['LOG_PATH'], maxBytes=5e+8, backupCount=10)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Prior to using ConcurrentLogHandler, I was using the RotatingFileHandler, and performing a logger.handlers[0].doRollover() would result in a "File busy" error triggered on the os.rename down the stack.

Is there a way I could force a rollover with this set up, or are there changes I should make in order to make this possible? I'm using Centos as a server, so the filesystem is UNIX/Linux. I can see a [filename].lock file on the log file at all times while my application is running.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ConcurrentLogHandler can be rolled over by logger.handlers[0].doRollover() indeed. The issue I had was that I used the RotatingLogHandler previously and a .lock file was left in the directory of the log, preventing it from being rolled over. Removing the lock file and keeping the ConcurrentLogHandler as the handler of choice (rather than RotatingLogHandler) solves the problem.